# What is the best practice to architecture an oAuth server and an API server separately?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, server, lumen

I am setting up an API for a mobile app (and down the line a website). I want to use oAuth 2.0 for authentication of the mobile client. To optimize my server setup, I wanted to setup an **oAuth server (Lumen)** separate from the **API server (Laravel)**. Also, my db also lives on its own separate server.

My question is, if using separate servers and a package like lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel do I need to have the package running on both server?

I am assuming this would be the case because the oAuth server will handle all of the authentication to get the access token and refresh access token functions. But then the API server will need to check the access token on protected endpoints.

Am I correct with the above assumptions? I have read so many different people recommending the oAuth server be separate from the API server, but I can't find any tutorials about how the multi-server dynamic works.

BONUS: I am migrating my DB from my API server, so I would assume I would need the oAuth packages migrations to be run from the API server also. Correct?